# Yii search with criteria and add parameters

Tags: search, activerecord, yii, criteria

I have one form and i want to search in my database. I create the object with all parameters but i have one problem. When write in one textfield search works fine and the query run correctly . When write two or more textfields params doesn't work and i have a fail execution of query :

WHERE
((((id_reservation=:id_reservation) AND (start=:start)) AND (end=:end)) AND
(fkCustomer.first_name=:first_name))

params doesn't replace.

```
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->with =array('fkCustomer');
    if(!empty($start))
    {
        $criteria->addCondition('start=:start');
        $criteria->params=array(':start'=>$start);
    }
    if(!empty($end))
    {

        $criteria->addCondition('end=:end');
        $criteria->params=array(':end'=>$end);
    }
    if(!empty($merge->customer_name))
    {

        $criteria->addCondition('fkCustomer.first_name=:first_name');
        $criteria->params=array(':first_name'=>$merge->customer_name);
    }
    if(!empty($merge->customer_surname))
    {

        $criteria->addCondition('fkCustomer.last_name=:last_name');
        $criteria->params=array(':last_name'=>$merge->customer_surname);
    }
    if(!empty($merge->customer_email))
    {

        $criteria->addCondition('fkCustomer.email=:email');
        $criteria->params=array(':email'=>$merge->customer_email);
    }
    $criteria->limit = 100;
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because in every `if` block you replace the `params` array. Build an array in the `if` blocks then add it to `$criteria->params` on the last line, outside the blocks.

For instance:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with =array('fkCustomer');
$my_params = array();

if(!empty($end))
{
    $criteria->addCondition('end=:end');
    $my_params['end'] = $end;
}

if(!empty($merge->customer_name))
{
    $criteria->addCondition('fkCustomer.first_name=:first_name');
    $my_params['first_name'] = $merge->customer_name;
}

// other ifs ..

//then
$criteria->limit = 100;
$criteria->params = $my_params;
```

Also, if I remember correctly, you don't need to write ':end' and ':first_name' in the `params` array, it will work without the colon.

Answer (score 1):

You also have the following alternative

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with = 'fkCustomer';

if(!empty($end))
{
    $criteria->compare('end', $end);
}

if(!empty($merge->customer_name))
{
    $criteria->compare('fkCustomer.first_name', $merge->customer_name);
}

// The following conditions ..

// Limit:
$criteria->limit = 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think this is the same problem i have before with the params variable, for avoid this problem i use the CMap::mergeArray function

this happens because you overwrite the variable each time that the condition passed over it.

This is the syntax for avoid it, its an example

```
$criteria=new CDBCriteria;
$criteria->addBetweenCondition("Date",$datestart,$dateend);
$criteria->addCondition("Type=:type");
//$criteria->params=array(":type"=>"1"); //This is wrong, overwrites addBetweenCondition params
$criteria->params=CMap::mergeArray($criteria->params,array(
    ":type"=>"1",
)); //This is ok, mantain all parameters in the params var
$query=Model::findAll($criteria);
```

Answer (score 0):

можно обратиться напрямую

```
 $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->with =array('fkCustomer');
    if(!empty($start))
    {
        $criteria->addCondition('start=:start');
        $criteria->params['start']=$start;
    }
    if(!empty($end))
    {

        $criteria->addCondition('end=:end');
        $criteria->params['end']=$end;
    }
    if(!empty($merge->customer_name))
    {

        $criteria->addCondition('fkCustomer.first_name=:first_name');
        $criteria->params['first_name']=$merge->customer_name;
    }
    if(!empty($merge->customer_surname))
    {

        $criteria->addCondition('fkCustomer.last_name=:last_name');
        $criteria->params['last_name']=$merge->customer_surname;
    }
    if(!empty($merge->customer_email))
    {

        $criteria->addCondition('fkCustomer.email=:email');
        $criteria->params['email']=$merge->customer_email;
    }
    $criteria->limit = 100;
```

Comment: what is можно обратиться напрямую??

Comment: @mayank-jain It's assembler ;)

Comment: I can not understand it. Is it related to programming ?